# Can we separate the variables of this real function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, symmetry

Let $f : (0,1)^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R_0$ be a continuous symmetric function such that, for all $u<s<t$ in $(0,1)$, there exists $g(t,s) \in \mathbb R_0$ such that $f(t,u)=g(t,s)f(s,u)$.

Does that mean that we can separate the variables of the function i.e write $f(t,s)=f_1(t)f_2(s)$ for some functions $f_1,f_2$ for all $s<t$ in $[0,1]$ ? It feels so obvious but I cannot find a proof. If it is not true (which would surprise me), can we add a small hypothesis so we can separate the variables ?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the hypotheses. Do you mean for all $u,t$ with $u<t$ there exists $s$ with $u<s<t$ and a function $g$ such that.... ?

Comment: By symmetry, wouldn't that imply $f_1=k \,f_2$ with $k$ a constant?

Comment: No for your first question, I mean what I wrote, and no for your second question: take for example $f(x,y)=\min(x,y)^2 \max(x,y)$. Clearly for $x<y$, we can separate the variables of $f$ i.e $f(x,y)=x^2 y$

Comment: In your example $f$ is not symmetric. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: Maybe we mean different things by symmetric: I mean $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for all $x,y$. $f$ is symmetric because min and max are.

Comment: Maybe the confusion comes from the following: I want to separate $f$ when $x<y$ (that why $s<t$ in the question)